# Demoiselle AppletExecute erro no manual

Tags: java, maven, demoiselle

Na documentação do Demoiselle do link:
http://demoiselle.sourceforge.net/docs/components/certificate/reference/2.0.0/html_single/#applet-configuracao

Para a criação do applet de exemplo, deve-se adicionar a dependência abaixo ao projeto:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.component</groupId>
    <artifactId>demoiselle-certificate-signer</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

E após isso estender a classe: **AbstractAppletExecute**. Mas a classe não é encontrada no pacore, nem mesmo o pacote a que ela pertence:

```
br.gov.frameworkdemoiselle.certificate.applet.action
```

Houve alguma mudança na forma de criar o applet? Algum usa isso?